# Caching Drupal 7 using boost module and Varnish, yet still getting a "MISS"(

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

I'm trying to do a little test, so I installed Drupal7 w/ following modules (expire, boost, varnish, purge, rules and token). I'm using`varnish-3.0.4-1.el5.centos.x86_64` in front of `httpd-2.2.15-29.sl6.x86_64`.

I added following into my `settings.php`:

```
// Add Varnish as the page cache handler.
$conf['cache_backends'] = array('sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.cache.inc');
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
// Drupal 7 does not cache pages when we invoke hooks during bootstrap. This needs
// to be disabled.
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

and I set following settings for varnish module inside of Drupal7:

```
# drush -r /usr/share/drupal7/ -l XXXXX vget varnish
varnish_bantype: "1"
varnish_cache_clear: "2"
varnish_control_key: "XXXXX"
varnish_control_terminal: "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:6082"
varnish_flush_cron: "0"
varnish_socket_timeout: 100
varnish_version: "3"
#
```

yet I keep getting `MISS`

```
# curl -I XXXXX
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 14:42:21 +0000
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
ETag: "1382625741"
Content-Language: en
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-url: /
x-host: XXXXX
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 14:42:21 GMT
X-Varnish: 1527289503
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: XXXXX
X-Cache: MISS

#
```

even though it seems like if I go to `Configuration`->`Performance` and then enable `Caching`, I'd end up with a HIT, yet `Status Report` would say following message (after enabling `Caching`) `Boost will not function properly while Drupal core cache is enabled. Disable Boost or the core cache.`

*** UPDATE ***

this is after enabling `boost`, as you see `Cache-Control:` *IS* in there, yet still getting `MISS` from Varnish(

```
$ curl -I http://XXXXX/node/1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux)
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 15:53:48 GMT
ETag: "802449-1da7-4e9cf1b11461e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7591
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 15:55:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-url: /node/1
x-host: XXXXX
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 15:55:46 GMT
X-Varnish: 1527308733
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: XXX.XXXXX.XXX
X-Cache: MISS

$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Pay attention to the `Cache-Control` header returned from Drupal:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

If `Cache-Control` is set to `no-cache`, Varnish will respect it by default. Either you must force caching from within Varnish in `vcl_fetch` or (much better), make Drupal deliver the proper header (`Cache-Control: public, max-age=X`). The simplest way to achieve the latter is to enable "Cache pages for anonymous users" in *Administration » Configuration » Development* and also set "Expiration of cached pages". You can hard-code those settings using:

```
$conf['cache'] = 1;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 3600; // 1h
```

You also may force the `Cache-Control` header by adding it explicitely using a custom module by implementing `hook_exit`. A reasonable save implementation looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_exit().
 *
 * @see drupal_serve_page_from_cache()
 */
function MYMODULE_exit($destination = NULL) {
  // If the client sent a session cookie, a cached copy will only be served
  // to that one particular client due to Vary: Cookie. Thus, do not set
  // max-age > 0, allowing the page to be cached by external proxies, when a
  // session cookie is present unless the Vary header has been replaced or
  // unset in hook_boot().
  $vary_header = drupal_get_http_header('vary');
  $max_age = !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) || isset($vary_header) ? variable_get('page_cache_maximum_age', 0) : 0;

  if (drupal_page_is_cacheable() && $max_age && $destination == NULL && !headers_sent()) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=' . $max_age);
  }
}
```

Also note that due to the fact that boost will also add a `Cache-Control` header, you still need to introduce some VCL logic in `vcl_fetch`. The following fragment will force Varnish to still store pages in the cache, even when they were delivered using boost with `Cache-Control no-cache`:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (beresp.http.X-Cached-By ~ "Boost") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1 h;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, yes I was looking at `Cache-Control` myself and I also saw that I forgot to enable `Cache pages for anonymous users` and set `Expiration of cached pages`, thank you for pointing it out for me)

but because I use `boost` module, under `Status Report` I'm getting following message (after enabling) `Boost will not function properly while Drupal core cache is enabled. Disable Boost or the core cache.`

Comment: @alexus: You may also add the Cache-Control header using a custom module. See updated answer.